Brownian motion, stopping time
Let $W$ be a 1-dimensional Brownian motion and define
$\tau_0 = \inf \{t > 0: W_t = 0\}$ ,
$\tau_L = \inf \{t > 0: W_t = L\}$.
For every $t > 0$ and every $x\in (0,L)$ how can I compute the probability that $x + W$ hits $L$ before $t$ and
before hitting $0$, i.e $P(\tau_L<\min\{t,\tau_0\} : W_0=x\})$ ?
